# External URL as a popup using Struts

Tags: javascript, jsp, popup, struts, menuitem

My requirement is as follows.
I log in to my application and there I have different menu items. When I click on a menu item, it should open `google.com` as a pop-up.

We are using Struts 1.3. In my `menuconfig.xml`, I have configured it as follows.

```jsp
<menu  name="google" link ="http://www.google.com/"   tooltip="google" 
</menu>
```

It opens `google.com` on the same page, not as a popup. I tried with

```jsp
<menu  name="google" link =window.open("http://www.google.com/")   tooltip="DOLIR Unemployed Workers Home" 
</menu>
```

and

```jsp
<menu  name="google" 
     <Item title="google" toolTip="google" location="http://www.google.com"/>
</menu>
```

None of these is working. Can anybody give me some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```jsp
<menu name="google" link="javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com/');" tooltip="DOLIR Unemployed Workers Home"></menu>
```

The link attribute value is used for the `href` in the HTML anchor tag. So, it should be a valid URL.